# How to show custom notifications or error message at admin panel for prestashop 1.7.7.7?

Tags: notifications, prestashop, admin, message, backoffice

​
Hi,

I've been trying a lot of options to manage an exception and show an error at admin panel but nothing seems to work.

I'm at the postProcess method of a custom module. After the user sends a csv file through a form and the data is checked (everything works fine here), if an exception occurs I need to show a message, stop and redirect to the same page.

I've tried this:

```
this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error',$msg);
Tools::redirectAdmin('index.php?controller='.$controller.'&token='.$token);
```

this:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
die(json_encode(array( 'error' => array($this->l(' Error') ))));
```

(that one works but shows a blank page with the message, not the message inside the admin panel)

also this:

```
$this->context->smarty->assign(array(
    'token' => Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
    'errors' => $this->errors
));
$this->setTemplate('ExcelProcess.tpl');
```

and {$errors|var_dump} at the tpl displays null...

... and many other options.

I can't find anything either about backoffice custom notifications at the PS docs, only about front custom notifications.

Any clue?

Thanks a lot!

Miguel

PostProces code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/175nhUPDlzi6T8rZjjE8Desnzq-mtYzNQ/view?usp=sharing

​Tpl code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17EONOCJ60L4Gp_GidzvwCQwMyTrRXapF/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Adding an error in **postProcess()** can be achieved by setting

```
$this->errors[] = $this->l('My error');
```

or

```
$this->context->controller->errors[] = $this->l('My error');
```

during your form submission checks.
Form will be rendered with your error messages into a red box.

If you want to show an alert without reloading the page instead, you'll have to perform an AJAX call to your AdminController, get back a JSON response and render your error message as a result of the execution of the call.

See [offical docs](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/front-controllers/#execution-order-of-the-controllers-functions)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It doesn't work for me. Could it be because of redirect function? I'm using Tools::redirectAdmin. I used redirectWithNotifications at front but it does not exists at backoffice. I'm not sure if Tools::redirectAdmin is having in consideration the $this-errors array or if I need to pass something else to the tpl.

Comment: When using "Tools::redirectAdmin" in your postProcess() method , you are basically reloading the page again... but it's not clear to me how your modules works. generally the postProcess() is called after a form submission and so it must show the result of the elaboration and not contain any logic - therefore it should avoid any redirection and render the result directly.